# Elixir Syntax Highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Can we please have syntax highlighting for [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org)?

I've had a look at the editor [advanced help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and Google's library documentation to find that it's not yet supported. Nonetheless I thought I'd ask for it to be added.

Comment: Okay, but why not ask Google? The Stack Echange team are not Prettify's maintainers.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Although I was guessing that maybe the Stack Exchange team branched off Google's work and used that; hence they could update their source code.

Comment: Done! Submitted a ticket at Prettify to add it. http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=319

Comment: The GitHub version of @dbarros ticket has been closed as fixed: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/319

Comment: I asked another question to see what else we need to do to get this to work soon: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316450/when-does-se-update-their-google-code-prettify-builds

Comment: From the duplicate is Elixir "supported in the prettify version Stack Exchange uses"?

Answer (score 12):

The [PR for adding Elixir support in code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/478) has just been merged. Stack Overflow should be able to build a new version of their [prettify-full.js](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.en.js?v=8613017edce4) with Elixir support.

Does anyone know what would be the process for requesting that?