# When does SE update their google-code-prettify builds?

Tags: support, status-planned, syntax-highlighting

Developers in the Elixir community have been trying to get [Syntax Highlighting support for the Elixir Language](https://elixirforum.com/t/elixir-syntax-highlighting-on-stackoverflow/2268) on Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange websites since 2013:

- We have gone through all the [information on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109) we could find
- Opened a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for the [Elixir Syntax Highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208528/elixir-syntax-highlights) on Meta
- Got the [PR for Elixir support](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/478) merged in the official source (back in 2017)

---

**But the latest build of Stackoverflow's [`prettify.js`](https://dev.sstatic.net/js/prettify-full.en.js) still does not have Elixir support.**

At first I thought it was because of the incorrect language name on `google-code-prettify`, so I sent in a [PR to rename it](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/562), but on rechecking the `PR['registerLangHandler']` statements in the build, I couldn't find anything for `ex` either.

I feel like we're missing something very obvious here. How do we get SO/SE to include a language in its `prettify.js` builds when there already is support for the language in Google Code Prettify?

Comment: You post a request here, as you just did.

Comment: Hey @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, do you have any insights/pointers on how we could speed the process up? Because I feel like this request has been lost in the pile again.

Comment: Please see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: This seems to have fallen between the cracks again? Elixir is a small community on SO but there's enough activity to see questions asked on a daily basis. People have obviously been (mis)using ruby syntax highlighting in the meantime but if there's a specific syntax highlighting available upstream for Elixir it seems it should be implemented. In comparison, Erlang has syntax highlighting and it has a similar number of questions on SO. It'd be great to see this resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Woo, status-planned! \o/

Answer (score 2):

We've officially switched to [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) network-wide. See the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/395497) for more details.

Comment: Does this mean that SE supports auto Elixir highlighting now (or will soon)?